# JavaFX: set text of pagination control buttons

Tags: java, javafx, pagination

How to programmatically set text of pagination control buttons?
[image: pagination control]

<kbd><</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>></kbd> -> to my own labels.

For instance:

<kbd><</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

To:

<kbd><</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

Comment: I guess what you are attempting went over my head because one would not normally want to change the actual numbers. Sorry, Good luck.

Comment: Ok if you say so, i hope you're not downvoting because you would not do that cause it's nonsense

Comment: I didn't down vote ya.

Comment: Ok sry, maybe the one who did it will explain to me why it is such a horrible thing to want to do this. I would prefer this over a simple downvote. Thanks for improving the post.

Comment: No problem @MethodMan.

Comment: Maybe there is a way... maybe.. if you create your own PaginationSkin and then apply it to the paggination.. I might actually search a bit if its possible and i will tell you. But i find it more easy to just use a TabPane instead, and customize it.

Comment: Thank you, i will consider the TabPane solution, but i really don't see any reason why JavaFX woudlnt support such simple feature.

Comment: Well after some search..it is in fact possible to access the ToggleGroup and each ToggleButton on it. But you cant change the Text without crashing the App cause the actual name correspond to the index of each pagination. In any case I am not going to show how to access them cause its very bad idea. TabPane is for sure the thing you are searching for.

Comment: Got it, thanks for searching. But i'd say maybe it's a bad idea, but it's also a bad design to link the name of elements with index from pagination :P

Comment: @MethodMan There are some confusing bindings with properties there indeed and bound checks depending on ToggleButton names.  But in any case i haven't found myself in a situation where i needed to use a pagination so I cant imagine a scenario which could be useful anyway :P

Comment: @JKostikiadis Actually i'm extending an already existing work so the pagination was already in place. There is a lot of pages idk if a Tabulation system can handle it nicely.

Comment: @MethodMan In that case you will have to create a custom control by yourself, its not actually really hard to do. Of course in order to provide more guidance about how you can implemented it I will need more information.

Comment: Yes but thanks i finally linked the pages to a listview and hided the pagination default controls :) No time to do something better